# Broadcast onReceive method does not get called

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

DUE TO COMMENTS, CODE IS UPDATED WITH MORE SPECIFIC INFORMATION.

**Manifest.xml**

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.x.x.x.MyReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.x.x.x.NOTIFICATION_INTENT_ACTION.TEST" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**MyReceiver.java**

```
internal class MyReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {

    companion object {
        const val NOT_ID = ".."
        const val NOT = ".."
        const val NOTIFICATION_INTENT_ACTION = "com.x.x.x.NOTIFICATION_INTENT_ACTION.TEST"

    }

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        // does not get called
    }
}
```

**CreatingIntent.java**

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
    mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    if (mAlarmManager != null) {
        mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 60000L, mPendingIntent);
    }
```

Problem: onReceive method inside of `NotRec` class does not get called. I tried to change Manifest to `<receiver android:name="FULL_PATH.receiver.NotRec" />` but it didn't change anything. Any ideas?

Comment: most **manifest registered receivers dont work in oreo** ..try registering programaticaly

Comment: For what functionality are you trying to make receiver?

Comment: What is `futureInMillis`? What type is the variable `Notification`?

Comment: @SantanuSur User is using `AlarmManager` to send the broadcast, not a manifest registered receiver.

Comment: @DavidWasser `futureInMillis` - time to fire alarm in future. `Notification` is type for variable `notification`.

Comment: How do you calculate futureInMillis?

Comment: @DavidWasser `System.currentTimeMillis() + 60000L;`

Comment: That's your problem! If you calculate the trigger time that way you need to use RTC_WAKEUP instead of ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP!

Comment: I will post an answer later when I am back in my office

Comment: @DavidWasser Unfort, it does not work. I updated original code with specific code I've now. Still not working.

Comment: Please try one more thing: remove the notification object from the Intent and see if the alarm triggers. I am travelling now so I cannot do any proper research.

Comment: @DavidWasser Thanks for help btw! I did try that and I get same result. This is confusing.

Comment: Remove 'exported="false"' from the <receiver> tag. I jusy noticed that!

Comment: @DavidWasser Looks like that was the reason. Do you know why?

Comment: When you mark the receiver as "not exported" that means it is private and cannot be triggered from another application. Therefore Alarmmanager cannot trigger the receiver. You must.

Comment: @DavidWasser Thanks for information. Feel free to repost it as "answer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
android:exported="false"
```

from the `<receiver>` declaration in the manifest.

If you don't "export" your receiver, the `AlarmManager` cannot trigger it. When you mark a component in the manifest as "not exported", this means that it is "private" and other applications (including system applications like `AlarmManager`) cannot launch or trigger the component.